# finding ECM data in Mpeg TS

Tags: mpeg, mpeg2-ts

I have a pcap trace with some scrambled Mpeg-ts data. I want to know if the ECM data is coming with it or not?

With the normal Wireshark MPEG-ts dis-sector I am not able to see that. So, is there any way to do so?

I have tried some Mpeg-TS readers by extracting the Mpeg data from pcap, but i am not able to find out if ECM is there or not?

Also, i think ECM can be In-band and out-band So, if its out-band, how a i come to know the same?

I have some PIDs inside the Mpeg headers, but I am not sure which PID refers to the ECM data and how will i be able to detect that.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to know pid of PMT, with format of PMT packet, you can know ECM pid, and check if any packets with ECM are there.